# Getting a 502 error when calling /bulkload API of IBM Graph

Tags: graph-databases, ibm-graph

When I call /bulkload with a graphml file, I get a `502 Server Error: Bad Gateway`. When I check the response it says

`Name cannot be in protected namespace: label, status_code=500`

How can I fix that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM graph has some restricted attribute/property names that can't be used. Here's a list of these restricted names `The following property key names are restricted: "key", "vertex", "edge", "element", "property", and "label".`

Here's a link to the documentation https://ibm-graph-docs.ng.bluemix.net/api.html

Change the attributed name you have from `label` to anything other than the restricted name and that should work